# Mapping to a static file in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-2.1

I'm running Play 2.1.1, and am trying to do something very simple : I want to map requests for /favicon.ico to /public/images/favicon.ico.

I have tried adding the following line to my routes :

```
GET     /favicon.ico                controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/images", file="favicon.ico")
```

This causes all my templates to error on compile, because due to reverse routing requirements all calls to controllers.Assets.at() now require two parameters rather than one.

What is the best way to handle this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the call to assets with another action to disambiguate reverse routes:

```
def favicon = Assets.at("/public/images", "favicon.ico")


GET     /favicon.ico                controllers.Application.favicon
```